# Aggregate daily sum over list of durations

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, aggregate-functions

#### Current situation

I have a table that tracks the usage of a certain resource. It looks like this:

```
started   | timestamp with time zone | not null
last_ping | timestamp with time zone |
stopped   | timestamp with time zone |
```

The `stopped` and `last_ping` fields may be empty. If they're both filled, `stopped` is relevant.

The start and stop dates can span only a few seconds or multiple dates.

#### Goal

I want to get a list of daily usage over the last 14 days.

#### Current status

I'm aware that I can get a list of the last 14 days:

```
SELECT day
FROM generate_series(CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE - 14, '-1 day'::interval) day;
```

I can get the total duration for each usage entry:

```
SELECT COALESCE(stopped, last_ping, started) - started AS duration
FROM api_sessionusage;
```

I can also combine the two queries and add a limit that only takes into account duration until midnight:

```
SELECT
  day,
  (
    SELECT SUM(
      LEAST(COALESCE(stopped, last_ping, started), day + interval '1 day') - started
    )
    FROM api_sessionusage
    WHERE started >= day AND started < day + interval '1 day'
  ) AS aggregated_duration
FROM generate_series(CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE -14, '-1 day'::interval) day;
```

The problem here is that usage sessions that end after midnight are only counted for the starting day, but the duration after midnight is not taken into account.

How can I rewrite the query so that I get an aggregated usage for each day during the last 14 days?

Comment: I think sample table data with desired output would help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [overlap and intersect operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-range.html) of timestamp range type:

```
select 
    day, 
    sum(upper(daily_range) - lower(daily_range))
from (
    select 
        day, 
        session_range * tstzrange(day, day::date + 1) daily_range
    from generate_series(current_date, current_date -14, '-1 day'::interval) day
    left join (
        select tstzrange(started, coalesce(stopped, last_ping, started)) session_range
        from api_sessionusage
        ) s
    on session_range && tstzrange(day, day::date + 1)
) s
group by 1
order by 1;
```

Note.

```
coalesce(stopped, last_ping, started) - started as duration
```

yields zero if both `stopped` and `last_ping` are null. Maybe it should be

```
coalesce(stopped, last_ping, current_date) --?
```

Comment: Wow, that's a great query. I didn't know about these operators :) Thanks!

Comment: I think I found one error though - the two `tstzrange(day::date - 1, day)` calls should be `tstzrange(day, day::date + 1)` instead, right?

Comment: Yes, a logical blunder ;) Thanks, the answer updated.